# How to proceduraly name column in 'as' statement

Tags: sql

I would like to procedurally name columns in this loop so I can iterate the ending char to have BeginDateA, BeginDateB, BeginDateC etc..

```
WHILE @i <= (select COUNT(plcNum) FROM #placements)
     BEGIN
          select
          plc.BeginDate as concat('BeginDate', char(@plcCharNum))
          from #placements plc
          where plc.plcNum = @i
          SET @i += 1;
          SET @plcCharNum += 1;
     END
```

I've tried doing the logic into a string variable and setting the column as that but it seems that it only accepts a string defined directly where it is being named

Comment: Ideally, find a better "level" to do this sort of presentation concern (i.e. what is *consuming* the results of this query and does it have better tooling to do this sort of re-formatting). In SQL, a particular query always produces a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their types and *names*. Which means either dynamic SQL or, like I say, picking a better tool.

Comment: It is going to a program that generates a word document. The columns match up to a bookmark of the same name in a Word document where it displays the corresponding value.  The program handles a ton of these documents so I can't code in a specific case for this so I was hoping to be able to do it in sql.

Comment: So that program is presumably already having to loop over the result sets somehow - can that program not keep track of which bookmark to access next?

Comment: Yes, it loops through the fields which are defined in an excel sheet (where it specifies data type etc..)  The fieldnames have to match in the stored procedure, the excel sheet, and on the word document

Comment: Since I can't dynamically name in sql, does it look like I'll have to hardcode these? (it's only grabbing 5 rows)  provided I can't mess with the document generation program?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

Comment: regular sql as far as I know.  There is other code at the top to declare the variables and create that temp table that I didn't add to code snippet